# How to embed an NSMenu inside a borderless window to create a fake menu bar

Tags: macos, cocoa, menubar

I am trying to create a fake menu bar in a cocoa application. I have been able to acomplish 95% of what I need, only the menu bar does not match mainMenu. See screen grab below of what I have so far.

I am using a "Pop Up Button" object in a xib to try to emulate the system menu bar. The problem is that it is a popup menu and does not look exactly like the mainMenu. Additionally, the title menu item does not hilite, and the popup menu has rounded corners that overlap the menu title. So, it's close, but no cigar.

Is it possible to create a fake menu bar inside a borderless window that matches the default system menu bar? If so, how?

I also tried using an NSStatusItem, which by default matches the system menu bar more closely than what I have been able to accomplish with a button, but I was unable to embed NSStatusItem into a window.

Ideally, if there is a way to embed an NSMenu directly in a windows view, that would be the best solution.

[image: fakemenubar]

[image: fakemenubar]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a custom button or view that looks and acts like the top-level item, then assign an `NSMenu` to your view's `menu` outlet.

You can then either implement `menuForEvent:` in your view and return your menu when the mouse is down, or alternatively call the `NSMenu` class method `+popUpContextMenu:withEvent:forView:` when the mouse is clicked.

This seems to be a slightly odd idea, by the way. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: Thanks Rob. I will try to implement your suggestion. I know it is probably against HIG, but I need it in order to show a minimalist menubar for an application which is an agent (UIElement = YES in plist). Ultimately the fake menu bar along with UIElement setting allows me to have a menubar, but no dock icon and hides my app from command+tab. So, menubar and dockless. The underlying reason for being an agent app is to reduce flicking when selecting my agent apps windows. I'll provide a link here when it is completed, and post some code as well.